# React Native test failed when using Formik and Yup as validation schema

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup, react-native-testing-library

I am trying to write some tests for a React Native component built using Formik. It's a simple form asking for username and password, and I want to use a validation schema built using Yup.

When I use the emulator and test the form manually, the form behaves as expected, error messages show up only when the input values are invalid.

However, when I try to write some automated tests with `@testing-library/react-native`, the behavior is not what I am expecting. The error messages show up in tests even if the provided values are valid. Below are the code:

```
// App.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { render, act, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';

import App from '../App';

it('does not show error messages when input values are valid', async () => {
  const {
    findByPlaceholderText,
    getByPlaceholderText,
    getByText,
    queryAllByText,
  } = render(<App />);

  const usernameInput = await findByPlaceholderText('Username');
  const passwordInput = getByPlaceholderText('Password');
  const submitButton = getByText('Submit');

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.changeText(usernameInput, 'testUser');
    fireEvent.changeText(passwordInput, 'password');
    fireEvent.press(submitButton);
  });

  expect(queryAllByText('This field is required')).toHaveLength(0);
});
```

---

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string().required('This field is required'),
  password: Yup.string().required('This field is required'),
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ username: '', password: '' }}
        validationSchema={Schema}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}>
        {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          errors,
          touched,
          validateForm,
        }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <View>
                <TextInput
                  onChangeText={handleChange('username')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('username')}
                  value={values.username}
                  placeholder="Username"
                />
                {errors.username && touched.username && (
                  <Text>{errors.username}</Text>
                )}
              </View>

              <View>
                <TextInput
                  onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                  value={values.password}
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
                {errors.password && touched.password && (
                  <Text>{errors.password}</Text>
                )}
              </View>

              <View>
                <Button
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                  // If I explicitly call validateForm(), the test will pass
                  // onPress={async () => {
                  //   await validateForm();
                  //   handleSubmit();
                  // }}
                  title="Submit"
                />
              </View>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
}
```

---

I am not sure whether I am writing the test correctly. I think Formik will automatically validate the form when the `handleSubmit` function is called.

Within the `App.js`, if I explicitly call the `validateForm`, the test will pass. However, it's not feeling right to change the implementation of the `onPress` handler just to cater for the test. Maybe I am missing some fundamental concepts around this issue. Any insights would be helpful, thank you.

---

Package versions:

```
"@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
"formik": "^2.2.6",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"yup": "^0.32.8"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @mohwarf I know it's a little bit late, I updated with an answer below, hope that helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got the time to revisit this issue. Although I am not 100% sure what's going on under the hood yet, I think the result I found might benefit others so I will share it here.

This problem is intertwined with two sub-problems. This first one is related to the `Promise` used in `React Native`'s module, the second one is related to the asynchronous nature of validation with `Formik`

Below is the code within `App.test.js` after modification, while keeping the `App.js` is unchanged,

```
// App.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react-native';

import App from '../App';

it('does not show error messages when input values are valid', async () => {
  const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText, queryAllByText } = render(<App />);

  const usernameInput = getByPlaceholderText('Username');
  const passwordInput = getByPlaceholderText('Password');
  const submitButton = getByText('Submit');

  await waitFor(() => {
    fireEvent.changeText(usernameInput, 'testUser');
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    fireEvent.changeText(passwordInput, 'password');
  });

  fireEvent.press(submitButton);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(queryAllByText('This field is required')).toHaveLength(0);
  });
});
```

Normally, we do not need to use `act` to wrap the `fireEvent` as the `fireEvent` is already wrapped with `act` by default thanks to the `testing-library`. However, since `Formik` performs validation asynchronously after the text value is changed, and the validation function is not managed by `React`'s callstack, so we need to manually wrap the `fireEvent` call with an `act`, or another convenient method: `waitFor`. In short, we need to wrap the `fireEvent.changeText` with a `waitFor` due to its asynchronicity.

However, changing the code to the above format does not solve all the problems. Although the test is passing, you will encounter warnings related to `act`. This is an known issue related to `Promise` as React Native's Jest preset overrides native Promise. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29303)

If you comment out the line

```
global.Promise = jest.requireActual('promise');
```

in `node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js` at around line 20, this issue will be solved. But directly modifying the files in `node_modules` is **NOT** recommended. A workaround would be setting up a jest preset to restore the native Promise like here (https://github.com/sbalay/without_await/commit/64a76486f31bdc41f5c240d28263285683755938)

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time and come back here with some thoughts. 

Comment: Would anyone have a solution for setting up a preset with a `jest-expo` config?

Comment: @conor909, I had to change my project to `expo` and still not able to fix these warnings. Did you make it?

Comment: were you able to use it with jest-expo @conor909?

Comment: Excellent findings. This problem has really given me such a huge headache. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is super helpful! Thanks! I'm trying to integrate this with jest-expo, this is what I came up with: https://gist.github.com/listiani13/df6921a45af50c1cc00ec5b0103ec10a